# Mouse action within apps

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, app

Running Ubuntu 22.04.3  Since upgrade, mouse is acting weird. ie: Any time any app wants me to browse to a file, the mouse only works to click on Documents, then will not advance to the next folder I click on.  Then in other apps such as App "WSJTX" mouse works on some buttons but will not work when clicking on a caller in the band activity window. This should switch the caller to the Rx Freuency window and enter the call of the caller into the Generated std Msgs window. clicking on any caller in the Rx Freq window should also enter the call sign in the Generated Sts Msgs windows. It does not. Clicks are totally ignored. Mouse motion up/d, Lt/Rt all work. But, no clicks allowed.

These apps all work in Raspberry PI computer which is running WSJTX software  All settings are the same.  WSJTX worked fine under 20.04

I don't know where to go from here.
Stan